# Search results' titles have small font size

Tags: bug, design

In [previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369127/why-are-titles-so-small-when-searching) there's an accepted answer which indicate there's an issue and why, but no one in stack overflow decided to accept or reject the bug, so it seems that the issue is closed.

In the search results the titles have small font size (13) 
While in default site it has normal font size (16)

For example in result of search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+Replace+chunks+in+nltk+with+specific+strings

It's hard to view search results due to its small size.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @AndréKool but it's still a bug, and no one will fix it if the duplicate answer is there's an issue and I can't fix it, no?

Comment: I don't really understand the second part of your comment. For the first part: yes it is a bug (the dupe is also tagged bug) I think.

Comment: I guess [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364131/how-to-renew-an-old-feature-request) is relevant, even if it talks about FRs and not bug reports.